# nodejs app works locally but not when deployed

Tags: node.js, express, web-deployment

I'm using iisnode to host a node app. I'm having trouble actually deploying it under my domain name. Here's the main file with two different starting points. The un-commented code is just a simple server that works correctly when accessed via my domain (so iisnode is mapping and handling the node app correctly). The commented code is the entry point for the express app I am working on, and this works when I view from a local host, but when attempting to access via my domain I receive a 'cannot GET application.js' error.

```
        var http = require('http');

        http.createServer(function (req, res) {
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
            res.end('Hello, world!');
        }).listen(process.env.PORT);

        //require('./app/init');
        //var server = require('./app/server');
        //module.exports = server.start(process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

Here is my server.js file. I think its a routing issue, I've substitued a console.log function for the indexRoute function, and it never fires. But I still don't understand why this works correctly accessing via localhost but not under my domain.

```
        var express = require('express');
        var routes = require('./routes');
        var app = express();

        function createApplication(environment) {
            app.get('/', routes.indexRoute);

            app.listen(process.env.PORT);
            return app;
        }

        module.exports.start = createApplication;
```

I can message a git link for full app if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying that you want to listen from all IP addresses, not just localhost by adding '0.0.0.0' as a parameter to listen. Also add a callback to see what happened.

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT, '0.0.0.0', function(err) {
  console.log("Started listening on %s", app.url);
});
```